# Jest encountered an unexpected token in a ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I am getting a Jest error when testing :-

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
```

This is the file that is causing the problem:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from '../index';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

I tried to do some research online however I think I have something wrong with my config files.

So I have the package.json:-

```
{
"name": "tasks.edit",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"homepage": "./",
"author": "Development Team",
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts-ts build && npm run postbuild",
    "build-css": "node-sass src/styles/sass/ -o src/styles/css/",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject",
    "postbuild": "rimraf build/**/*.map",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js test:watch",
    "start-js": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:default": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll -u",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass src/styles/sass/ -o src/styles/css/ --watch --recursive",
    "debug": "node --debug-brk --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/jest -i"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "ckeditor4-react": "0.1.0",
    "email-validator": "2.0.4",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "react-joyride": "2.0.3",
    "react-redux": "6.0.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/react-joyride": "2.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.0.0",
    "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "1.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"
},
"jest": {
    "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json"
    ]
}
```

}

This is the jest.congig.js

```
module.exports = {
"name": "Tasks.Edit",
// Setup Jest
"roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
],
"testEnvironment": "node",
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/"],
// transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
"transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)?$": "babel-jest" 
},
"testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
"moduleNameMapper": {
    'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/(.*)$': 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/$1'
},
"moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
],
"globals": {
    "window": {}
},
// Setup Enzyme
"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupEnzyme.ts",
```

}

and this is my .babelrc

```
{
"presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  ]
```

}

Is this configuration correct? Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: And which file causes the problem?

Comment: You omitted some important details. The error should contain other info like file name. `Jest encountered an unexpected token` should contain a token it refers to. *This is the file that is causing the problem* - what is a path to this file? The problem is that the file wasn't fully transformed. And from the question it's impossible to say why. It's even unknown if it's specific to Babel or TS. You try to investigate Babel but testRegex says tests are TS and there's no TS config in the question.

Comment: I have found a fix for that error, see my answer.  I still have a problem with that test, however it is something different now.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably when updating package dependency, "babel-core" dependency may have been updated to 6.xx.x, it should be "7.0.0-bridge.0" for jest to work.

Reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1879#issuecomment-412300256 https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1879#issuecomment-435194932

Comment: Tried the above link however still having the same problem unfortuantely

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get rid of the Jest error by editing the .babelrc file:-

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/react" , 
      "@babel/env" 
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```